# How to receive image dragged from Safari webpage with SwiftUI `.onDrop()`

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, safari, webkit

I'm not able to receive image dragged from Safari webpage in my SwiftUI app on macOS. I suppose Safari uses different mechanics, because it works properly when it comes to Chrome and Firefox. I use `.onDrop()` but it results empty `providers` no matter what kind of `UTType` used. Below is my code but output `no provider available`.

So, what `UTType` it is when dragging image from Safari webpage, and how can I implement it in `.onDrop()`

```
.onDrop(of: [.url, .fileURL], isTargeted: $isTarget) { providers -> Bool in
    if let provider = providers.first,
       let identifier = provider.registeredTypeIdentifiers.first {
        print(identifier)
        provider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: identifier) { data, error in
            // Do something here
        }
    } else {
        print("no provider available")
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Safari will send the actual image UTType -- `.jpeg`, `.gif`, `.png`. But, strangely, for me, I don't get a `provider` when it does that...

Comment: Hi did you ever figure out why .onDrop is getting an empty NSItemProvider from Safari? I am also encountering this exact same thing in my SwiftUI program. I have tried looking at adding all the UTI types, adding more sandbox entitlements to no avail. If you have figured it out, please share what you have changed. Thank you very much.